# How to see, which day of the week most of the commits occurred on, using grep?

Tags: git, grep, git-log

Have a file that contains git log for the repository, want to see How to use grep to see which day of the week most of the commits occurred on.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please specify the format of data in the file. Git log is customizable.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that the file you have is named `gitlog.txt` and inside it contains output of standart `git log` command.

Then after some piping to `grep`, `cut`, `sort` and `uniq`

```
$ cat gitlog.txt | grep "Date: " | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
   1862 Wed
   1858 Sat
   1844 Sun
   1806 Tue
   1571 Thu
   1398 Fri
    992 Mon
```

Note: you can debug the command removing trailing pipe, like `cat gitlog.txt | grep "Date: " | cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sort | uniq -c`

Comment: Thank You! Yes, it's a text file that I've outputted the commit logs to. Your answer is helpful, but I was looking to print only the day with the most commits; in above example's case - Wed.

Comment: You are weclome, just pipe it to `head -n 1 | cut -d ' ' -f 2`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot! In my case, I had to pipe it to head -n 1 | cut -d '  ' -f  5